Unable to classify (a problem with color ramp in QGIS)
When I try to add all the missing unique values from the raster (classify) to change the color of LiDAR DEM, it calculates endlessly with no results (always at 0%). What could be causing this problem and how can I fix it?


The number of unique values in a raster with float datatype can be extremely large. Are you sure you want unique values renderer? Try "Singleband pseudocolor" with "discreate" interpolation and "Equal interval" mode if you want height classes, like this

Thanks for the suggestion! I will try it.
